# Using Gnuplot in Android

Tags: android, gnuplot

Is there a way to use gnuplot in an Android app?  I can use gnuplot for a Java desktop app using JavaPlot, but it depends on the binary being installed on your computer, which Android won't have.  There are several gnuplot apps for Android, so I know it has to be possible somehow, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: No, I think there's no easy way to do it since the gnuplot binary isn't Java. My best guess is that the gnuplot apps I've seen mimic the functionality, but don't run on the real gnuplot binary. I wish there were a plotting package native to the JVM as good as gnuplot but I haven't found one.

Comment: Agreed, I have searched everywhere and tried allot of different libs http://jzy3d.org/ but no luck to get it working in android, Maybe this is a opportunity to create one of my own as a open source project. I just want to create a surface chart without paying for it.

Comment: Have you tried using AChartEngine? http://www.achartengine.org/
It's free to use. I use it for my Android app, ThriftView, for drawing pie charts.

Comment: Can't post this as an answer, but to use JavaPlot, you'd need to also ship a build of gnuplot for Android in your apk, and ensure JavaPlot can find the binary.